# Error configuring settings and importing models with a custom Django command

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-settings

I'm somewhat new to Django and have been trying to write a custom management command to get data from a txt file into my database. I seem to be having a lot of trouble running the command and I can't figure out what's wrong. I have two different problems, though maybe they are related. When i try to run the command I get this error:

```
joshs-mbp-4:Commands Josh P$ python vatsim_pull.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vatsim_pull.py", line 10, in <module>
    from flights.models import (Personal, ActiveFlights, Flights, ActiveControllers,     Controllers, Airports)
ImportError: No module named flights.models
```

My apps are just in my base project directory, but incase i'm doing something wrong in settings, here's my settings.py:

```
from sys import path
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
path.append(BASE_DIR)
TEMPLATE_DIRS = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/var/www/static/',
)


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'Users',
    'registration',
    'flights',
)



MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)





ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#databases


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/New_York'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader')
STATICFILES_FINDERS = ("django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
 "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder")


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'Users.UserProfile'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

The other issue i'm having is if i comment the import model line, i get an error message about configuring my settings

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

This hasn't happened any other time besides when i try to run this script in the command line.

I have this in my manage.py:

```
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

and here's the actual command (sorry if this is too much code, i'm new to using stack overflow). I thought that running settings.configure() would do it, but i've had no luck:

```
import csv
import requests
import datetime
import math
import sys
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.management.base import NoArgsCommand, CommandError
from datetime import timedelta
from django.utils.timezone import utc
from flights.models import (Personal, ActiveFlights, Flights, ActiveControllers, Controllers, Airports)
from decimal import Decimal
from django.db.models import F
django.conf.settings.configure()

class Command(NoArgsCommand):
    help = "Scrapes flight info from Vatsim"


    def unicode_csv_reader(unicode_csv_data, dialect=csv.excel, **kwargs):
        # csv.py doesn't do Unicode; encode temporarily as UTF-8:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(utf_8_encoder(unicode_csv_data),
                                dialect=dialect, **kwargs)
        for row in csv_reader:
            #decode UTF-8 back to Unicode, cell by cell:
            yield [unicode(cell, 'utf-8') for cell in row]

    def utf_8_encoder(unicode_csv_data):
        for line in unicode_csv_data:
            yield line.encode('utf-8')

    def getNmFromLatLon(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
        R = 3443.89849 # km
        theta1 = math.radians(lat1)
        theta2 = math.radians(lat2)
        dtheta = math.radians(lat2-lat1)
        dlon = math.radians(lon2-lon1)

        a = math.sin(dtheta/2) * math.sin(detheta/2) + math.cos(theta1) * math.cos(theta2) * math.sin(dlon/2) * math.sin(dlon/2)
        c = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1-a))

        d = R * c

        return round(d)



    def pilotInsert(row):


        call_sign = row[0]
        pilotId = row[1]
        user_rating = int(row[16])
        if (user_rating == 0):
            user_rating = 'Not Rated'
        elif (user_rating == 1):
            user_rating = 'VATSIM Online Pilot'
        elif (user_rating == 2):
            user_rating = 'VATSIM Airmanship Basics'
        elif (user_rating == 3):
            user_rating = 'VATSIM VFR Pilot'
        elif (user_rating == 4):
            user_rating = 'VATSIM IFR Pilot'
        elif (user_rating == 5):
            user_rating = 'VATSIM Advanced IFR Pilot'
        elif (user_rating == 6):
            user_rating = 'VATSIM International and Oceanic Pilot'
        elif (user_rating == 7):
            user_rating = 'Helicopter VFR and IFR Pilot'
        elif (user_rating == 8):
            user_rating = 'Military Special Operations Pilot'
        elif (user_rating == 9):
            user_rating = 'VATSIM Pilot Flight Instructor'

        real_name = row[2]
        date_time = updateTime
        flight_date = updateTime[0:11]
        client_type = "Pilot"
        alt = row[7]
        lon = Decimal(row[6])
        lat = Decimal(row[5])
        serv = row[14]
        ground_speed = int(row[8])
        transpond = int(row[17])
        flight_heading = int(row[37])
        aircraft = row[9]
        tascruise = int(row[10])
        depairport = row[11]
        altitude = int(row[12])
        destairport = row[13]
        deptime = row[21][0:2] + ":" + row[21][2:4]
        actdeptime = row[22][0:2] + ":" + row[22][2:4]
        altairport = row[27]
        flight_remarks= row[28]
        flight_route = row[29]
        Route_String = lat + "," + lon + ";"
        flight_duration = datetime.datetime.utcnow() - actdeptime
        flightStatus = ""


        #Deal with Personal Table
        #
        #
        if (Personal.objects.filter(cid=pilotId).exists() == False):
            newPersonal = Personal(cid = pilotId, realname = real_name, pilot_rating = user_rating)
            newPersonal.save()
        else:
            personal = Personal.objects.get(cid=pilotId)
            if (personal.pilot_rating != user_rating):
                personal.pilot_rating = user_rating

        #Deal with Flights Table
        #
        #
        if (Flights.objects.filter(date = flight_date, callsign = call_sign, cid = cid).exists() == False):
            origAirport = Airports.objects.get(icao=depairport)
            origLat = origAirport.lat
            origLon = origAirport.lon
            dist = getNmFromLatLon (lat, lon, origLat, origLon)
            newFlight = Flights(date = flight_date, callsign = call_sign, cid = pilotId, planned_aircraft = aircraft, planned_tascruise = tascruise, planned_depairport = depairport, planned_altitude = altitude, planned_destairport = destairport, planned_deptime = deptime, planned_actdepttime = actdeptime, plannedaltairport = altairport, planned_remarks = remarks, planned_route = flight_route, time_logon = timelogon, RouteString = Route_String, duration=flight_duration, total_distance = distance)
            newFlight.save()
        else:
            flight = Flights.objects.get(date = flight_date, callsign = call_sign, cid = cid)

            #Get last lat/lon
            colonCount = 0
            colon1 = 0
            colon2 = 0
            comma = 0
            for i in range(len(flight.RouteString), 0, -1):
                if ((flight.RouteString[i] == ";") and (colonCount == 0)):
                    colon1 = i
                    colonCount +=1
                elif ((flight.RouteString[i] == ",") and (colonCount == 1)):
                    comma = i
                elif ((flight.RouteString[i] == ";") and (colonCount == 1)):
                    colon2 = i
            prevLat = flight.RouteString[colon2+1:comma]
            prevLon = flight.RouteString[comma+1:colon1]

            #Update Total Distance
            flight.RouteString = F('total_distance') + getNmFromLatLon(lat, lon, prevLat, prevLon)



            #Update Route String
            flight.RouteString = F('RouteString') + Route_String
            if ((flight.outRamp == Null) and (ground_speed < 50) and (datetime.datetime.utcnow() > actdeptime)):
                flight.outRamp = updateTime
                flightStatus = "On The Ground"
            if ((flight.offGround == Null) and (ground_speed > 50)):
                flight.offGround = updateTime
                flightStatus = "Airborne"

            #Get Destination Airport Coords
            destAirport = Airports.objects.get(icao=destairport)
            destLat = destAirport.lat
            destlon = destAirport.lon

            if ((flight.onGround == Null) and (ground_speed< 50) and (getNmFromLatLon(lat, lon, destLat, destlon) < 5)):
                flight.onGround = updateTime
                flightStatus = "Arrived"
            flight.save()

        #Deal with ActiveFlights Table
        #
        #
        if (ActiveFlights.objects.filter(datetime = date_time, cid = pilotId, callsign = call_sign).exists() == False):
            if (flightStatus == ""):
                lastActive = ActiveFlights.objects.filter(cid = pilotId, callsign = call_sign).latest('datetime')
                flightStatus = lastActive.flight_status

            newActive = ActiveFlights(datetime = date_time, cid = pilotId, callsign = call_sign, clienttype = client_type, latitude = lat, longitude = lon, server  = serv, altitude = alt, groundspeed = ground_speed, transponder = transpond, heading = flight_heading, flight_status=flightStatus)
            newActive.save()

            #Delete old active flight entry
            oldActive = ActiveFlights.objects.filter(cid = pilotId, callsign = call_sign).exclude(datetime = updateTime)
            oldActive.delete()


    def atcInsert(row):
        date_time = updateTime
        _date = updateTime[0:10]
        call_sign = row[0]
        atc_id = row[1]

        user_rating = int(row[16])
        if (user_rating == 0):
            user_rating = 'Ground Controller'
        elif (user_rating == 1):
            user_rating = 'Tower Controller'
        elif (user_rating == 2):
            user_rating = 'TMA Controller'
        elif (user_rating == 3):
            user_rating = 'Enroute Controller'
        elif (user_rating == 4):
            user_rating = 'Senior Controller'

        client_type = "ATC"
        freq = row[4]
        lat = row[5]
        lon = row[6]
        serv = row[14]
        facility_type = row[18]
        if (facility_type == 0):
            facility_type = 'Other'
        elif (facility_type == 1):
            facility_type = 'Observer'
        elif (facility_type == 2):
            facility_type = 'Clearance Delivery'
        elif (facility_type == 3):
            facility_type = 'Ground'
        elif (facility_type == 4):
            facility_type = 'Tower'
        elif (facility_type == 5):
            facility_type = 'Approach/Departure'
        elif (facility_type == 6):
            facility_type = 'Center'

        visual_range = int(row[19])
        time_logon = row[36]
        date = updateTime
        totaltime = datetime.datetime.utcnow() - time_logon

        if (Personal.objects.filter(cid=atc_id).exists() == False):
            newPersonal = Personal(cid = atc_id, realname = real_name, atc_rating = user_rating)
            newPersonal.save()
        else:
            personal = Personal.objects.get(cid=atc_id)
            if (personal.atc_rating != user_rating):
                personal.atc_rating = user_rating

        if (ActiveControllers.objects.filter(cid=atc_id, callsign=call_sign, datetime=date_time).exists == False):
            newActiveATC = ActiveControllers(datetime=date_time, callsign=call_sign, cid=atc_id, clienttype=client_type, frequency=freq, latitude=lat, longitude=lon, server=serv, facilitytype=facility_type, visualrange=visual_range, time_logon=timelogon)
            #delete old active controller
            oldActiveATC = ActiveControllers.objects.filter(cid=atc_id, callsign = call_sign).exclude(datetime = updateTime)
            oldActiveATC.delete()

        if (Controllers.objects.filter(date=_date, callsign= call_sign, cid = atc_id).exists() == False):
            totaltime = datetime.datetime.utcnow() - time_logon
            newController(date=_date, callsign = call_sign, cid = atc_id, facilitytype = facility_type, TotalTime = totaltime)
        else:
            controller = Controllers.objects.get(date=date, callsign= call_sign, cid=atc_id)
            controller.TotalTime = controller.TotalTime + (updateTime - controller.lastUpdate)
            controller.lastUpdate = updateTime
            controller.save()






    # CSV READING BEGINS
    #
    #
    #

    def handle(self, **options):

        client_rows = []        
        r = requests.get('http://info.vroute.net/vatsim-data.txt')
        data = r.text.splitlines()
        update = ""
        updateTime = ""
        newUpdate = True

        reader = unicode_csv_reader(data,delimiter=":")

        for row in reader:
            if (row != []):
                if "UPDATE = " in row[0]:
                        date = row[0]
                        update = date[9:]
                        updateTime = update[0:4] + "-" + update[4:6] + "-" + update[6:8] + "T" + update[8:10] + ":" + update[10:12] + ":" + update[11:13] + "+00:00"
                        if (ActiveFlights.objects.filter(datetime=updateTime).exists() == True):
                            newUpdate = False

                elif (row[0] == u'!CLIENTS'):
                    for row in reader:
                        if (row[0] == ";"):
                            break
                        client_rows.append(row)
        if (newUpdate == True):
            for row in client_rows:
                print row[16]
                if (row[3] == 'PILOT'):
                    pilotInsert(row)
                elif (row[3] == 'ATC'):
                    atcInsert(row) 

        ## Delete flights that have been missing for an hour

        notUpdated = ActiveFlights.objects.exclude(datetime = updateTime)
        for flight in notUpdated:
            if ((flight.datetime + timedelta(hours=1)) <= datetime.datetime.utcnow()):
                flight.delete()
        ## Delete missing controllers
        missingController = ActiveFlights.objects.exclude(datetime = updateTime)
        for controller in missingController:
            controller.delete()
```